# large inductance compensation methodology in chip power delivery network

Tags: impedance-matching

i am trying to learn on compensation networks design.
Suppose our power delivery network from VDD to the chip has very high impedance at certain frequency.
i know that we cn use smith chart to design such network.
i dont know the exact terminology or if smithchart is the best way.
i'll be glad for a recomendation on methodology for these purposes.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like you're overcomplicating things. The supply (VDD) should have a low impedance which is usually achieved by using **decoupling capacitors**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Suppose our power delivery network from VDD to the chip has very high
> impedance at certain frequency.*

Then will likely be the root cause of likely power supply problems and this is what needs to be fixed. Fixing this can mean a series of distributed decoupling capacitors at each node where the chip's VDD pin is. It can also mean using proper ground planes for 0 volts.

> *i know that we cn use smith chart to design such network.*

Well, you could use a smith chart but, these days, you'd use a simulator to mimic the disposition of Vdd and ground and see where the problem frequencies are. Fix with capacitance or increased/improved copper thicknesses and ground plane.

> *i'll be glad for a recomendation on methodology for these purposes.*

Model the problematic power feed within a simulator. Simulators are good and free and will eat this problem up with ease.

Comment: Hello Andy,thank you very much for the real life solution answer.
Could you please help me with how ground plane thickness or trace thickness affects line impedance?if there is some manual.
Thanks.

Comment: @ron398 here is a flat PCB trace inductance calculator that basically tells you that a wider track has less inductance: https://chemandy.com/calculators/flat-wire-inductor-calculator.htm

Comment: And, if you had the trace above a ground plane you will get much lower inductance as shown by this microstrip calculator: https://www.emisoftware.com/calculator/microstrip/

Comment: Hello Andy,what about thickness intuition and ground bounce intuition.
could you please help me with an intuition regarding these?
Thanks.

Comment: I can't really help other than to say that the thicker the conductor, the lower the inductance will be and therefore the lower the impedance will be at a certain frequency. Ground bounce is something that isn't all that intuitive @ron398

Comment: Hello Andy ,from the web link bellow thickness has no effect?
where is the effect of thickness? 

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/microstrip-inductance-calculator/

Comment: @rocko445 what has this got to do with the question above?